# Swipe event not firing on android stock browser

Tags: android, jquery

I'm using Touchswipe to trigger events based on swipe right and swipe left. After a lot of testing, i found that touchswipe is not working on android stock browsers since touchswipe is not firing swipe events on stock browsers. Any work around for this?

Code to trigger:

```
  $(function() {      

  //Enable swiping...
  $("#content").swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
      if(direction == "left"){

      }else if(direction == "right"){

      }else if(direction == "down"){
        // event.preventDefault()
      }
    },
     threshold:0
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you show us the code, please?

Comment: @blackpanther Code added.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a lot of issues i found that swipe event on android STOCK browsers can't be triggered with code from an external Js file but works if put on same html file. Weird but works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery mobile to support the swipe functionality. The developer API is given [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html).

The difference here, is that instead of calling `$(document).ready(function() ...)` we can call: `$(document).bind('pageinit')`

Comment: Its fixed buddy, seems like swipe won't trigger from external js only Android stock browser. but if put on same html file works fine.

Comment: Totally weird!!Thanks for looking into this.